# Disable check of camel case rule in eslint

Tags: constants, eslint, camelcasing, disable

I have a large JavaScript file with multiple eslint rule violations. I am trying to disable them and address them one at a time. The code below shows that I can disable them all with no trouble, but not the rule about camelcase and perhaps other individual rules. The approaches I have used should work according to the   eslint documentation, but there must be a flaw in my interpretation.

The code is short and it does not eliminate the error concerning camel case.

```
/* eslint-disable  /* eslint-disable//  works but gets everything.
`/* eslint (camelcase) : 0 */
    /* eslint camelcase : ["error", {ignoreDestructuring:true}] */
```

`const Lesson_1 = {title:'The Home Row Keys.'},'lesson': 'jjj fff jjj fff'}`

Just get the same camelcase error without any change.  The eslint documentation says just disable the entire rule  but does not specify a method other than listed above.

Answer (score 119):

To disable the rule for a file add next line at the begging of a file:

for JavaScript files:

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
```

for TypeScript with enabled @typescript-eslint plugin:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
```

To disable the rule for all files in a project add next line to the eslint config file:

for JavaScript files:

```
rules: {
  ...

  'camelcase': 'off',
}
```

for TypeScript with enabled @typescript-eslint plugin:

```
rules: {
  ...

  '@typescript-eslint/camelcase': 'off',
}
```

Comment: @typescript-eslint/camelcase rule was deprecated in favour of naming-convention rule.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/camelcase.md

Answer (score 27):

For `TypeScript`, we can change the rules in the `eslintrc` file.

```
rules: {
  "camelcase": "off",
  "@typescript-eslint/camelcase": ["warn"]
}
```

We can set `"off"` or `"warn"` here. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules

Comment: *@typescript-eslint/camelcase* is deprecated

Answer (score 19):

This works for me

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
```

Comment: Even though I am using @typescript-eslint -- this worked for me.  Eslint v6.8.0

Comment: where do you put that??

Comment: Inside the JavaScript File. At the beginning

Answer (score 18):

Update For **TypeScript**:

`@typescript-eslint/camelcase` is [deprecated](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/camelcase.md)

use `@typescript-eslint/naming-convention` instead

```
rules: {
  ...

  "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "off"
}
```

Or for **single files**

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention */
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 4):

Use following code, and add it to each corresponding file containing variables against **camelcase rules** :

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/class-name-casing */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't disable this is a bad practice but in case you wanted you can add a rule to your .eslintrc.json file in the root of your project and set camelcase to as shown in the example.

```
    "extends": "standard",
    "rules": {
        "camelcase": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to use:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/naming-convention */
```

After moving Angular to eslint

Answer (score 2):

Try the following options.

1. Use the next-line or same-line syntax

```
// eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
const Lesson_1 = {title:'The Home Row Keys.'},'lesson': 'jjj fff jjj fff'}
```

or (see after semi-colon)

```
const Lesson_1 = {title:'The Home Row Keys.'},'lesson': 'jjj fff jjj fff'}; // eslint-disable-line camelcase
```

2. Try disabling the entire file by adding the following as the first line of your file. This should ignore all camel casing errors in the entire file.

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
```

**Note:** Always check if the configuration file work against the eslint you're running. Means, there can be multiple installations of eslint - Global & local. So make sure you are running the right one. Also check the rules object in the `.eslintrc` configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To disable on a single file `*.js` or `*.ts`; put the following at the top of that file.

```
/* eslint @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires: "off" */
```